# Get path from OS X file reference URL alias (file:///.file/id=...)

Tags: macos, shell, url, path

In PyQt4 on Apple Mac OS X, we get a [file reference URL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW6) to a drag-and-dropped file in the following format:

```
file:///.file/id=123456.78901
```

This, interestingly, is not a valid file URL, or at least it doesn't transparently resolve in most applications — there is no `/.file/id=...` file in the filesystem.

Using just shell, how do I dereference this NSURL or file reference or alias (or whatever it's called) into a valid path to file on the filesystem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can use `osascript`, an [AppleScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript) interpreter available on default OS X installs, run with the following script:

```
osascript -e 'get posix path of posix file "file:///.file/id=123.456" -- kthxbai'
```

Prints `/Users/josh/Downloads/paste-10837081.py`.

Comment: OK. it worked. I had to write osascript(...). It worked without the "-e"

Comment: Python (e.g. in virtualenv) may lack the appropriate osascript package. Thus, it's safer to run above shell command in a [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).

Answer (score 5):

In Swift you can use URL.standardized to get the valid path from a reference URL.  So in Swift 4 - to get the file name from a drag-and-dropped file you'd do something like...

```
let fileType = NSPasteboard.PasteboardType (kUTTypeFileURL as String)

extension NSPasteboardItem {
    func fileURL ()->URL? {
        if let refURL = self.string(forType: fileType) {
            return URL (fileURLWithPath: refURL).standardized
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is a NSURL object, to get a path from it:

```
NSString *filePath = [fileURL path];
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished in Python using the PyObjC bridge.

```
from Foundation import NSURL # depends on PyObjC

# convert a URL file reference to a POSIX path
NSURL.URLWithString_('file:///.file/id=6571367.8602676692').path()

# convert a path file reference to a POSIX path
NSURL.fileURLWithPath_('/.file/id=6571367.8602676692').path()
```

Be sure you to select the appropriate NSURL method for your data type or else you'll get the wrong value back.

### Resources

- [NSURL API doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl?language=objc)
- [API discussion of file reference URLs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1408631-filereferenceurl?language=objc)
- [PyObjC](https://pypi.org/project/pyobjc/)